# Trying to print double quotes(") or atmark (@)

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, printing

In my laptop,

I am trying to print double quotes(") by pressing shift + single quotes button.

But it prints @ instead of ".

Similarly I am trying to print atmark(@) by pressing shift + 2 button.

But it prints " instead of @.

I don't know why it prints in this manner.

I don't know why this is happening.

Is there any way to make it work normally, like pressing respective button to print respective symbol.

Comment: Looks like your keyboard is set as a UK English keyboard.  What keyboard do you have?

Comment: Yeah I have changed from  UK English to Indian Keyboard. It is working correctly thank you @jehad

Comment: @jehad Go ahead and post this as an answer. Srini's problem has been fixed.

Comment: My version of the answer posted.  Thanks @varfirstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your keyboard is set as a UK English keyboard, and you want English (India).

Go to **Region and Language** settings in Windows (through Start menu or Control Panel).  Then change the Keyboard settings.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for being a positive member of the community.

Comment: These days there's an _input_ language and a _display_ language- if nought else but for the sake of consistency, they should match.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard is probably incorrectly configured for UK/US.
This answer presumes that you're after the US layout, if not, then substitute as appropriate.

1. Press Start and type `Region & Language settings` (or a part of), and open the control panel.
2. In this screen, you will likely see that the computer's language is configured for "*English (United Kingdom)*".
3. If "*English (United States)*" is *not* available, then click `Add a language`, search for it
4. Then select "*English (United States)*" is available, then click on it and click `Set as default`.

Comment: yeah after changing language from English (United Kingdom) to English (India), it works normally.Thank you a lot